# How to manipulate or clear the undo-redo chain of a TextInputControl?

Tags: javafx, textarea, undo-redo

I'm implementing a custom embeddable command line console control in javafx8, based upon the stock TextArea control.

I'd like to be able control what does and does not go into the internal undo/redo stack: user edits on the command line (yes) but application responses to those edits and subsequent output to the readonly portion of the text area I am maintaining (no).

The TextInputControl includes a nicely designed UndoRedo linked list, but everything to do with it seems to be private.

How do i manipulate the TextInputControl undo stack either directly or indirectly to e.g. pop a link off it after appending output text?